# How can I perform an AND operation on a single column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, boolean-logic

I have a table with two columns;

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `QUESTION_CATEGORY_RELATION` (
  `question_id` int(16) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(16) NOT NULL,
  KEY `category_id` (`category_id`),
  KEY `question_id` (`question_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `QUESTION_CATEGORY_RELATION` (`question_id`, `category_id`) VALUES
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(2, 1),
(2, 2);
```

[image]

I want to create a query that will search for a question_id with content_id 2 and content_id 3

e.g.:

```
SELECT *  
FROM `QUESTION_CONTENTS_REL` 
WHERE `content_id` = 2 AND `content_id` = 3
```

Comment: Doesn't that query work?

Comment: it is giving me 0 rows in output.

Comment: But do you have rows that contain content_id 2 and 3? And I'm not sure what the ' is for?

Comment: yes but this query will look for single entry with values 2 and 3 and hence it will return 0 rows.

Comment: What you want is called relational division. Here's a question with quite a lot of ways to do it: **[How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)**

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT question_id
FROM QUESTION_CONTENTS_REL
WHERE content_id in (2, 3)
group by question_id
having count(distinct content_id) = 2
```

Comment: hi juergen d
I want to perform AND operation but IN clause will give me answer of 2 OR 3 OR BOTH, with above data, i want only question_id 1 in answer because it is the only entry having both the content ids.

Comment: Add a `)` in the `having` clause and this is what the op is asking for.  *[@AnuSad : The `IN` clause does mean `2 OR 3`, but then the `COUNT()` in the HAVING clauses means `and has both`.  I suggest that you **try** the code before stating that it is incorrect.]*

Comment: @juergen: OP didn't want this... He wanted those `question_ids` that have **both** `content_ids`, not **either**

Comment: Anu Sad and ppeterka -- please read Dems' explanation before dismissing the answer. The only way for a returned row to have two distinct content_ids are for it to be associated both with 2 and 3, so only question_id=1 qualifies

Answer (score 1):

I might be missinterpreting but i think you are looking for `OR` instead since the content_id is a key

```
SELECT * FROM QUESTION_CONTENTS_REL WHERE `content_id`= 2 OR `content_id` = 3
```

Comment: i am looking for the answer which will give me only question id 1 in output because it has content_id=2 AND content_id=3

Comment: this will use OR and not AND ... you will have content_id 2, content_id 3 and content_id 2+3

Comment: OP didn't want this... He wanted those `question_ids` that have **both** `content_ids`, not **either**

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT q1.question_id 
FROM `QUESTION_CONTENTS_REL` q1
JOIN `QUESTION_CONTENTS_REL` q2 on q1.question_id=q2.question_id
WHERE q1.`content_id` = 2 
AND q2.`content_id` = 3
```

This is not the nicest solution available, as it has a JOIN, for example in Oracle, I'd do this:

```
SELECT q.question_id 
FROM `QUESTION_CONTENTS_REL` q
GROUP BY q.`question_ID`
HAVING SUM(case when q.`content_id` = '2' then 1 else 0 end)>0 
AND SUM(case when q.`content_id` = '2' then 1 else 0 end)>0
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks it is working,
but i would like to ask, there is many-to-many realtion in question and contents hence created this third table.
and requirement is I want questions having contentIDs=2 as well as 3.
so, according to requirement, is my design correct ?
your query worked.

Comment: @AnuSad How do you want to handle if the number of `content_id`s to be compared are increased?